# My Dad has two passports with different names

Tags: indian-citizens, passport-renewals

My dad had a passport in 1980 and lost it when he applied for a second the agent who applied for the passport did it on a different name, We found the old passport recently. Both the passports were never renewed.

Now I need to renew his passport the old one that he had has the correct name on it whereas the second one is made on his nickname.

My question is do I have to submit both the passports or just the old one for renewal. And will there be any issue if I don't show the second passport.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Both of the passports are Indian citizen passports?

Comment: If you submit both passports, the Passport Office will see your father's entire passport history and your father can explain how the two names came to differ. If, on the other hand, you submit only one passport and the Passport Office looks and finds the other, your father will be seen as hiding his history, and may be refused for misrepresentation. Why would you risk that result?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify question in comments. Putting on hold for now.